# Upload Images on database .NET, C#

Tags: c#, .net

What is the easiest way to upload images to database using C#?

Comment: I believe that this may be a dup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see: [Best way to save/load pictures with .Net & SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485746/best-way-to-save-load-pictures-with-net-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to upload them to database. Just write a query with sqlparamerters and set a parameter value to Byte[] of image.

If you ask me, Whats the easiest way of storing them in database. Then I would say [BLOB streaming engine](http://blobstreaming.org/). Its the best solution, but its available only for MYSQL. It has a tiny webserver embedded in it. Which allows  to stream upload images to database using HTTP PUT.