# How to save data to mysql from android?

Tags: android, mysql

i have an android app that writes data to a text file. The text file has the following contents

```
0.459, 0.957, 9.692,2014/05/11 12:40:027916020051941
0.536, 0.919, 9.577,2014/05/11 12:40:027916080051941
```

i would like to save the contents of this text file to a mysql table on a server. Can i do this from within the android app? i.e. load the textfile and save its contents on the server?
please help

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily. 
You will first need to set up your environment for working with MySql using the JDBC API which is described here: http://zetcode.com/db/mysqljava/ , you have to have Mysql server installed on your computer first. 
when you are connecting ok to the database you can do the following described here [How to store .txt files MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278759/storing-the-txt-file-to-the-mysql-database).

Answer (score 0):

Send a POST Request from the android side to a script on your server side which fetches values from the POST request and inserts it into the MySQL Server.

Read from File : [How To Read/Write String From A File In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376807/how-to-read-write-string-from-a-file-in-android)

Sending a post request in android : http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

insert into db using php on the server : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_insert_php.htm