# Saving Attachments from mail item to Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, outlook

I need to read the mail contents like To, CC, Subject, Body, Attachments of a mail and store it in Database tables. I am using the below code.

```
  EmailMessage msg = (EmailMessage)item;
  foreach (var col in msg.CcRecipients)
   {
   ccList += col.Address.ToString() + ";";
   }

   foreach (var col in msg.ToRecipients)
   {
   toList += col.Address.ToString() + ";";
   }
```

Similarly I can read Body and Subject. Problem is in reading Attachments
How to read the Attachments and store it in Database.

I can use msg.Attachments. But What would be the type of the object. Please suggest some better solution to store the attachments to Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably need a table with at least two columns.  A varbinary to store the actual file (byte[]), and another column of varchar (string) to store the mime type.

Answer (score 0):

Relate a EmailMessage to zero or many Attachments. Use `varbinary(MAX)` as the SQL column type. Or `FILESTREAM`. References below:

1. [varbinary(max) tames blob](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/varbinarymax-tames-blob) (with code)
2. [tsql binary & varbinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx) (msdn)
3. [Compare Options for Storing Blobs (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403405%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) (msdn)
4. [How To Update A BLOB In SQL SERVER Using TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820971/how-to-update-a-blob-in-sql-server-using-tsql) (StackOverflow question)
5. [Blob data in huge SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453602/blob-data-in-huge-sql-server-database) (StackOverflow question)
6. [An Introduction to SQL Server FileStream](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/) (good tutorial)
7. [Download sqlserver varbinary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516606/download-varbinary-data-from-sql-server) (StackOverflow question)