# Database Tables For Images And Videos

Tags: database

I'm trying to build Database design for news website.

The problem that I faced is:
should I build tables for images and videos in the database??

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not. Databases are not geared towards good handing of large files. Consider using file system for that.

There are tons of similar discussions around so I just drop links to them here:

- [Storing a file in a database as opposed to the file system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952/storing-a-file-in-a-database-as-opposed-to-the-file-system)
- [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database

Comment: can you clarify that please??

Comment: @Ibrahim Added some links to help you understand all pros and cons